# What is `.file` in root boot volume for?

Tags: macos

I've just noticed a dodgy file in the root boot volume `/.file` It has all permissions disabled `---------- 1 root admin` and is 0 bytes. Mac OS 10.14.7

Has anybody seen this before or know what it's used for?

Comment: That file is normal and is supposed to be there. Leave it alone.

Comment: /. and /.. are for navigating the directory tree. Just don't delete anything until you are sure you know what they are for.